# Logic behind multiplication method using a 1D Array of LongNumber class

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, logic

I am having problems with the logic behind this multiplication method. It is using a 1D array of LongNumber. We can't use the Math class, must write our own logic. The two previous methods were addition and subtraction, I am having issues with how to setup the for loop in order to move one num index as we stay at the index of the other, and then changing to the next index of the number that wasn't moved.

This logic has been more confusing for me, addition and subtraction were all in once simple for loop and it was easy, with multiplication I cant figure out how to setup the loop so it only moves num index and not num2, so we can get the correct product.

```
public static Long_Number multiply(String num,String num2)
{   
    //data
    String resultString3 = "";
    Long_Number result3 = new Long_Number("");
    int total, carry = 0, temp;
    int v1 = 0, v2 = 0;

    //set longest length to indexrange
    int indexrange = num.length();
    if(num2.length()>indexrange)
        indexrange = num2.length();

    //logic 
    for(int i = 0; i < indexrange; i++)
    {
        if(num.length()-1-i >= 0)
            v1 = (num.charAt(num.length()-1-i)-'0');
        else
            v1 = 0;
        if(num2.length()-1-i >= 0)
            v2 = (num2.charAt(num2.length()-1-i)-'0');
        else
            v2 = 0;

        sumofdigits = v1 * v2 + carry;
        carry = sumofdigits % 10;
        System.out.println(sumofdigits + "hi" + carry); //test print    
     }
    result3.setNumber(resultString3);
    return result3;
}
```

Comment: Keep playing with it.  You have a lot of issues with the code posted, so I would delete it all and start from scratch.  Design the algorithm on paper first before trying to code it.  You will get it.